# Uncaught TypeError: $(…).dialog is not a function even after including the CSS files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having an issue on generating Dialog box even after including Jquery source imports. Here are my imports.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Html & JQuery code is as follows:

```
<button id="view_Data" type="button" "width:35%">View MySQL Data</button></br>

<div id="pw_dialog" title="Operator Authentication">
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input id="Password" name="Password" type="password">
            <button id="submitPW" type="button"> submit</button>
        </form>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
    $( "#pw_dialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });
    });
    $("#view_Data").click(function(){
        $( "#pw_dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    })
})
```

I have tried with other version imports also. But still getting the same error.
Please help!
Thank you!

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle that shows the problem? I am having trouble duplicating your issue.  Here is a jsfiddle that seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/92fxtygc/

Comment: I can't see any error.

Comment: You don't need both `$(document).ready(function() {` and `$(function() {` remove the `$(document).ready(function() { }` wrapper

Comment: This code is working in one of my systems which is CentOS based. But this same code is not working in Debian Os.

Comment: @janR i tried your answer also,but still getting same error.

Comment: Do you have another jQuery loaded in your page

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: is it because you try to use http to access https? try change the https to http and check if it load correctly

Comment: @Se0ng .i removed s froom https as you said. but no use

Comment: please check in ur browser console, network tab, refresh 1 time and see if any red dot or red file appear, click on it and check what is the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `$(document).ready(function() { }`

Your javascript should just be:

```
$(function() {
   $( "#pw_dialog" ).dialog({
       autoOpen: false
   });

  $("#view_Data").click(function(){
    $( "#pw_dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
  })
});
```

As per the docs found [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/):

```
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ugnfj8nx/1/

Comment: Here is my console output.Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):190)
    at fire (jquery-latest.js:3119)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-latest.js:3231)
    at Function.ready (jquery-latest.js:3443)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-latest.js:3474)

Comment: I think problem with in the imports.

Comment: Looks like it, try using a local copy of jquery to see if that resolves the issue

Comment: I have included local file in my css folder.still getting same error

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="css/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="css/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: it's not the css file that would cause this, it's either jQuery or jQuery.UI

Comment: which files i have to include and where i have to include?.

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Grab a local copy of both of those and try again

Comment: i included those two files in css folder. No use.

Comment: where does jquery-latest.js come from? do you have multiple javascript files included on your page?

Comment: it's working. jquery-latest.js is included in some other folder.i have not observer that. Thank you so much for your help!